# How the change EVERY children tag (of a specific nature) to a different one using BeauifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, replace

In the Given `HTML` below:

```
given = """<html>
    <body>
        Free Text: Above
        <ul>
            <li> data 1 </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li> 
                        <ol start = "321">
                            <li> sub-sub list 1 
                                <ol>
                                    <li> sub sub sub list </li>
                                </ol>
                            </li>
                            <li> sub-sub list 2 </li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                    <li> sub list 2 </li>
                    <li> sub list 3 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <p> list type paragraph </p> data 3 </li>
        </ul>

        Free Text: Middle
        
        <ul>
            <li> Second UL list </li>
            <li> Second List part 2 </li>
        </ul>

        Free Text : Below
    </body>
</html>"""
```

Now I want to ask:

How can I change the Children `<li>` tags whose `ANY` of the parent is

to something else, say `<SOME>`

 (please don't ask why would I want to and I won't be able to render it. I have reasons)

In a nutshell, I want my above code to look like:

```
result = """<html>
    <body>
        Free Text: Above
        <ul>
            <li> data 1 </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <SOME> 
                        <ol start = "321">
                            <SOME> sub-sub list 1 
                                <ol>
                                    <SOME> sub sub sub list </SOME>
                                </ol>
                            </SOME>
                            <SOME> sub-sub list 2 </SOME>
                        </ol>
                    </SOME>
                    <SOME> sub list 2 </SOME>
                    <SOME> sub list 3 </SOME>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <p> list type paragraph </p>data 3 </li>
        </ul>

        Free Text: Middle
        
        <ul>
            <li> Second UL list </li>
            <li> Second List part 2 </li>
        </ul>

        Free Text : Below
    </body>
</html>"""
```

I tried (with and without `tag.decompose`:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(given, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.find_all(['li']):
    if tag.find_parents("li"):
        new_tag = soup.new_tag("SOME")
        new_tag.string = tag.text
        tag.replace_with(new_tag)

result = str(soup)
```

but it doesn't seem to work on `depth > 1` such as inner tags like `sub-sub list` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.replace_with()` may simply rename it with `.name` to keep structure:

```
for tag in soup.select('li li'):
    tag.name = 'SOME'
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<html>
    <body>
        Free Text: Above
        <ul>
            <li> data 1 </li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li> 
                        <ol start = "321">
                            <li> sub-sub list 1 
                                <ol>
                                    <li> sub sub sub list </li>
                                </ol>
                            </li>
                            <li> sub-sub list 2 </li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                    <li> sub list 2 </li>
                    <li> sub list 3 </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <p> list type paragraph </p> data 3 </li>
        </ul>

        Free Text: Middle
        
        <ul>
            <li> Second UL list </li>
            <li> Second List part 2 </li>
        </ul>

        Free Text : Below
    </body>
</html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for tag in soup.select('li li'):
    tag.name = 'SOME'

soup
```

Comment: Will it work for Dynamic queries too? I mean what if it's `OL` etc? I'm trying to make it generic. Main motive is to keep the first `<li>` element and change Each and Every **NESTED**  `<li>` to `<SOME>`

Comment: To be more generic  use `soup.select('li li')` what selects all `<li>` taht are children of a `<li>`

Comment: Oh thanks, that worked. I actually tried ```for tag in soup.find_all('li', recursive=True):
    if tag.find_parents("li"): tag.name = "SOME"``` and it gave the exact same result which you described.